# Excel sheet not shifting more than a limited rows

Tags: apache, excel, apache-poi

I have an excel template in 'sheet' variable. I need to add database values into new rows as shown. I used functions from apache poi to edit the excel file.

```
sheet.shiftRows(RowId, sheet.getLastRowNum(), Rows);
```

But it's not adding more than 16 rows. Initially it seemed like the pageheight was 1 and so it couldn't take beyond one page, but even when height was changed to 9 using

```
sheet.getPrintSetup().setFitHeight((short)9);
```

The same error was coming. Any idea why this is happening ?

Arguments for the shiftRows function are 15, 25, 12

Answer (score 0):

```
   HSSFPrintSetup printSetup = sheet.getPrintSetup();
    sheet.getPrintSetup().setFitWidth((short) 1);
    sheet.getPrintSetup().setFitHeight((short) 0);
    sheet.setAutobreaks(true);
    printSetup.setLandscape(true);
```

Comment: Thank you. I found the error it is because after 25 rows there are null rows. So I created new rows.